# How do I create multi-layout website with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, layout, webforms, themes

I need to create a website with different layouts (templates, themes). For example, as the CMS so you can load different themes that the manager will choose through the control panel. Where can I find a simple example project? I use asp.net webforms. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple master pages to have different layouts.

Also you can use the theming functionality from asp.net webforms.

You can define themes for a single Web application, or as global themes that can be used by all applications on a Web server. After a theme is defined, it can be placed on individual pages using the Theme or StyleSheetTheme attribute of the @ Page directive, or it can be applied to all pages in an application by setting the  element in the application configuration file. If the  element is defined in the Machine.config file, the theme will apply to all pages in Web applications on the server.

**Page Themes**

A page theme is a theme folder with control skins, style sheets, graphics files and other resources created as a subfolder of the \App_Themes folder in your Web site. Each theme is a different subfolder of the \App_Themes folder. The following example shows a typical page theme, defining two themes named BlueTheme and PinkTheme.

```
MyWebSite
  App_Themes
    BlueTheme
      Controls.skin
      BlueTheme.css
    PinkTheme
      Controls.skin
      PinkTheme.css
```

**Global Themes**

A global theme is a theme that you can apply to all the Web sites on a server. Global themes allow you to define an overall look for your domain when you maintain multiple Web sites on the same server.

Global themes are like page themes in that they include property settings, style sheet settings, and graphics. However, global themes are stored in a folder named Themes that is global to the Web server. Any Web site on the server, and any page in any Web site, can reference a global theme.

You can find more details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx